# Get all values from one dimension in a Perl hash

Tags: perl, associative-array

I have a hash built like this:

```
my %datavalue2;

foreach my $alert ( @{ $data } ) {

    my @date = split(/ /,$alert->{logged});

    $status = $alert->{status}->{status};
    $type   = $alert->{type};

    if  ( ! defined $datavalue2{$date[0]}{$type}{$status} ) {
        # print "initialisation de la variable du ".$date[0]." de type ".$type." avec le status ".$status."<br>";
        $datavalue2{$date[0]}{$type}{$status}=1;
    }
    else {
        # print "incr&eacute;mentation de la variable du ".$date[0]." de type ".$type." avec le status ".$status."<br>";
        $datavalue2{$date[0]}{$type}{$status} +=1;
    }

    # print "<br> ";
}
```

How can I get the sum of all `$status=1` for one date and each type?

I want something like `$total_type1 += $datavalue2{2016-08-15}{*}{1}` but I don't know the syntax. Is it possible?

Comment: Need some source data as an example I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sum up the values for each type. Either you do it with the existing loop

```
my %datavalue2;
my %totalsPerStatus;
foreach my $alert ( @{ $data } )
{
   ...
   $totalsPerStatus{$date[0]}{$status} //= 0; # initialize total per status
   $totalsPerStatus{$date[0]}{$status}++; # increment total
}

$total_type1 += $totalsPerStatus{'2016-08-15'}{1};
```

... or afterwards ...

```
sub getTotalPerStatus {
    my ($datavalue2, $date, $status) = @_;

    $total = 0;
    foreach my $type (keys %{$datavalue2->{$date}}) {
        if (exists $datavalue2->{$date}->{$type}->{$status}) {
            $total += $datavalue2->{$date}->{$type}->{$status} 
        }
    }
    return $total;
}

$total_type1 += getTotalPerStatus(\%datavalue2, '2016-08-15', 1);
```

Comment: You don't need to initialise, `++` (and autovivify) does that implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that ***none of this code is tested*** as I have only a tablet to use at present

First of all, there's no need to check whether a hash element exists before incrementing it. Perl will *autovivify* the elements as necessary, so you can write your code like this

```
my %datavalue2;

for my $alert ( @$data ) {

    my @date = split ' ', $alert->{logged};

    $status = $alert->{status}{status};
    $type   = $alert->{type};

    ++$datavalue2{$date[0]}{$type}{$status};
}
```

Your data structure isn't ideal for doing what you've asked for, and you may well be better off redesigning it. But what you want is certainly possible

```
my $date = '2016-08-15';
my $total_status1 = 0;

$total_status1 += $_->{1} // 0 for values %{  $datavalue{$date} };
```